# What is the best way to assigning elements to multiple targets with lower cost?

Tags: algorithm, colors, combinations, pseudocode

I'm trying to find the best algorithm for assigning elements to multiple targets with the lower cost possible.

To activate targets (UPPERCASE) you need 1 or 2 specific elements (lowercase) using a [colour theory logic](http://www.lizohsiek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/color-theory.jpg):

- YELLOW   needs: yellow
- BLUE     needs: blue
- RED      needs: red
- GREEN    needs: green or yellow+blue
- ORANGE   needs: orange or yellow+red
- VIOLET   needs: violet or red+blue

Think the problem as doors which have to be opened with one-time-use key.
All doors have to be opened with 1 key of the same colour or 2 keys of a primary colour. Keys are in a maze, and the cost is the distance from them to the door.

Once you have an array with all possible combinations (very simple example) and apply the algorithm you have this:

```
//Doors: G (GREEN), B (BLUE), Y (YELLOW)
//Keys: b, (blue), y (yellow), g (green)
Input:
    [{Door: G,  Keys: [b,y], cost: 1},
     {Door: G,  Keys: [g],   cost: 10},
     {Door: B,  Keys: [b],   cost: 5},
     {Door: Y,  Keys: [y],   cost: 3}]

Output:
    [{Door: G,  Keys: [g],   cost: 10},
     {Door: B,  Keys: [b],   cost: 5},
     {Door: Y,  Keys: [y],   cost: 3}]
    Total cost: 18
```

(Notice that even opening green door with blue+yellow keys has the lower cost (1), it uses 2 keys needed by other doors, so can't be part of the final solution)

Which could be the best way to find the lower cost combination if:

- All doors need 1 or 2 keys to success
- There is no need to use all the keys
- A key can only be used once

---

I'm using A* in another part of the code, and I've adapted it for this propose, but I think it's not efficient enough (I need to use this algorithm thousands of times to solve a maze). I've also explored another [combinational optimization solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization), but I'm not sure witch one to use.

Any help or orientation will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Could this also be seen as a classifier problem? Such as restating the question into "how yellow is element X" or "Is element x rather yellow or blue?" ?

Comment: Not sure if I follow you 100%. Elements can only be used once but it's no necessary to use all of them. So I think that I can't base the solution on the elements.

I'm trying to find a most common similar problem but I'm not being lucky. Sorry if I can explain better.

Comment: It might be helpful if you added some classical Input: Output: specification to your problem description. I have a hard time to figure that out from the question as it is now. In my previous comment I assumed that the Input were colors, the output a color class (RED, BLUE YELLOW,...).

Comment: uou, yes!, I'll add an example, thanks :)

Comment: @user2225104 Example added. I hope now is easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you - now I think I understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt to improve speed would be to stick to the branch and bound solution you already have (your A*).

In contrast to chess or go or similar, this problem can be solved in a brute force way. The number of nodes in the search tree is small enough, that you could keep them all in memory.

Hence, my first attempt would be to add a transposition table to your A*, which stores the already found values for a node.

I once wrote a program to solve a game (bunny bashing). Without transposition table it took like 10s to solve. With transposition table it was done in 35ms.

Then, it might be possible to add pruning techniques (alpha beta, mayhaps).

Also, possibly it would speed up replacing the A* (which operates on graphs) with a search algorithm which operates on a tree.

Comment: Thank you. Let me find a little more info about the terms you have introduced to me and I let you know if I'm able to improve my algorithm.

Comment: Please note that if you look up "Transposition table", your case is simpler than the usual case. You can have a PERFECT mapping from node to value. Usually, you cannot and the hash tables capacity is smaller than the number of nodes.